# Flot fails to render charts on certain browsers

Tags: javascript, charts, flot

I have a simple line chart that contains 2 series, with the x-axis being a date and the y-axis an integer. The code that illustrates this is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="flot/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #overview-plot24 {
            width: 94%;
            margin-left: 20px;
            height: 220px;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            var plotOptions = {
                //Options go here
                xaxis: {
                    mode: "time",
                    tickLength: 5,
                    reserveSpace: true,
                    autoscaleMargin: 0.01
                },
                yaxis: {
                    min: 0
                },
                legend: {
                    show: false
                },
                series: {
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    shadowSize: 0
                },
                grid: {
                    hoverable: true,
                    clickable: true
                }
            };

            var plot2 = $.plot(
                    '#overview-plot24', [
                        {
                            label: "Alerts",
                            color: "#FC8200",
                            data: [
                                    [Date.parse("2013-03-19 15:00"), 9650],
                                    [Date.parse("2013-03-19 16:00"), 33124],                                
                                    [Date.parse("2013-03-19 17:00"), 27806],
                                    [Date.parse("2013-03-19 18:00"), 24143],
                                    [Date.parse("2013-03-19 19:00"), 7573],
                            ]},
                        {
                            label: "Scores",
                            color: "#8000FF",
                            data: [                            
                                    [Date.parse("2013-03-19 15:00"), 26407],
                                    [Date.parse("2013-03-19 16:00"), 93973],
                                    [Date.parse("2013-03-19 17:00"), 77760],                                
                                    [Date.parse("2013-03-19 18:00"), 68715],
                                    [Date.parse("2013-03-19 19:00"), 20383],
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    plotOptions
            );
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="overview-plot24"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is correctly rendered in Chrome and Opera, but the series fails to be rendered on Safari and Firefox. 
[image: Correct rendering]Chrome renders is correctly.
[image: Bad rendering]Safari and Firefox renders it incorrectly.

This is perplexing as the examples on the flot web page render correctly on all browsers and I'm struggling to see where my code differs!

For those interested in running the code directly, zip archive containing all you need is [available](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/21682354/Internet%20Posts/Flot%20Render%20Issue/FlotBadRender.zip).

Comment: This isn't the problem, but note that your lists have a comma after the last item.  Modern browsers don't care, but that sort of thing (in object literals especially) will cause errors in older ones, like IE7.

Comment: That's not a problem for me as I am fortunate enough to be able to target IE9 or later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could this be a problem with the Date.parse function not working as you expect on Safari and Firefox? I think the date formats that are recognised are implementation dependent, and may not be consistent across different browsers.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/javascript-date-parse) for more details

Comment: That was the problem. Changing the date format made it render correctly. It is strange that there was no error in the Javascript console.

Comment: Date.parse just returns 'NaN' rather than throwing an error if it can't understand the date, and I guess Flot doesn't throw errors for NaN values either.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is **not in Flot** or its rendering but **in the JavaScript**, specifically in the format you use for date.

Format you're using for date is not valid (see horizontal axis in the rendered chart) because that format `2013-03-19 19:00` is recognized by IE and Chrome but not FF and Safari.

The only format you're sure every browser will read is `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ` so in your case you should change string in your code to `2013-03-19T19:00`. Take a look to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4321270/regarding-javascript-new-date-and-date-parse) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/javascript-date-parse?rq=1) posts on SO for other details (or [this little tutorial](http://javascript.info/tutorial/datetime-functions) about dates).

Comment: Thank you for the additional links. It was indeed the date format that was an issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue and, although I fixed the date format it didn't solve the problem. The issue turned out to be [a bug in Flot](https://code.google.com/p/flot/issues/detail?id=322) where it will not graph the data if you specify `min` and `max` options for time values on the x-axis.

Once I removed the `min` and `max` it worked like a charm in all browsers.