# convert date from dd/mm/yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Okay so I have a table with a column date and date values like " 2013-05-03 " since the table is dynamically filled. I have converted the date using php and the date now looks 
like " 03/05/2013"

php conversion:

```
<td> <?php echo date("d/m/Y", strtotime($row['date'])) ?> </td>
```

Since I have a edit functionality in my page and I also use 
I want to convert the date back to its original format so that chrome could recognize it

```
var date = new Date(feed date in dd/mm/yyyy format);
    $("#customer_date").val(date);
```

I tried the above method. But looks like the conversion doesn't happen.
what could be a different approach?
thanks!

Comment: What did you do at ‘feed date in dd/mm/yyyy format’?

Comment: Working with dates in JavaScript is pretty shitty, You don't have a template tool or anything like you do in eq. PHP. I use moment alot: http://momentjs.com/

Comment: Do not work directly with dates. Do not split them and do not parse them unless you're really sure of what you're doing. Take a look http://stackoverflow.com/a/17064680/1207195 for some hints.

Comment: I would not bother, you will have to do server-side validation anyway so I would do it all there. Although I am not sure what you mean with `so that chrome could recognize it`...

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Do a simple split and join

```
var date = "03/05/2013";
var newdate = date.split("/").reverse().join("-");

"2013-05-03"
```

Comment: Only if his **customers** will **accept dates in that format** (only) and he has never to **convert** that string **to a date object**. It **may** satisfy his requirements but it should be pointed out...

Comment: So simple! Thank you so much (even 3 years after your answer)!

Comment: Glad you found it useful! As others have pointed out you have to be careful that your date is in the right format since you are making that assumption :)

Comment: Great answer, What about the reverse? I mean if we have date 2013-05-03  to 03-05-2013?

Answer (score 4):

As your date is really just a string the quickest way would be to split it like this.

```
date = "03/05/2013";
date = date.split("/").reverse().join("-");

$("#customer_date").val(date);
```

Example here http://jsfiddle.net/GNFGP/1

Answer (score 1):

if you want more powerfull date formatting, you can use date format function written by [Steven Levithan](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com) [here](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format)

```
var date = dateFormat(new Date("Thu Oct 14 2010 00:00:00 GMT 0530 (India Standard Time)"), 'yyyy-mm-dd');
```

Answer (score 0):

'2015-04-03 16:50:05' gives '03-04-2015 16:50' with below code

```
var formattedTime = '2015-04-03 16:50:05'.substr(0,10).split('-').reverse().join('-')+" "+'2015-04-03 16:50:05'.substr(11,5);
```