# Convert D/M/YYYY to YYYY/MM/DD (ex : 1/6/2015 --> 2015/06/01 not 2015/6/1)

Tags: javascript, date

Hello I have to convert a date like `D/M/YYYY` to `YYYY/MM/DD`

Ex : 1/6/2015 --> 2015/06/01 not 2015/6/1

I have some conditions to be met :

- When it convert the month like Jan "1" must give : 01, 
  Feb "2" must give : 02 etc
- I have to use `Date()`

  ```
  var st = "D/M/YYYY"
  var dt = new Date(st);

  var maFonction = function(userdate) {
    var day = st.getDate();
    var month = st.getMonth();
    var year = st.getFullYear();
    var maDate = year + "/" + day + "/" + month;
    return maDate;
  }

  console.log(maFonction(st));
  ```

I tried but it doesn't works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert date from dd/mm/yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19709793/convert-date-from-dd-mm-yyyy-to-yyyy-mm-dd-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

use this function to convert date from D/M/YYYY to YYYY/MM/DD

```
var convertDate = function (userdate){
    var d = userdate.split("/");
    return  d[2] + '/' +
            ('0' + d[1]).slice(-2) + '/' +
            ('0' + d[0]).slice(-2) + '/';
};

convertDate("3/1/2016"); // returns 2016/01/03
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var date = new Date("1/6/2015");

var dt = ('0' + (date.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + '/'
             + ('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2) + '/'
             + date.getFullYear();

alert(dt.split("/").reverse().join("/"));
```

Comment: @JeanA:- You are welcome. You can accept the answer if that helped you( A tick mark symbol  turns green when clicked)