# Getting the date from a Bootstrap React form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do I extract a yyyy-mm-dd timestamp from the following?

```
handleDateChange = e => {}

<Form.Group as = {Col}>
  <Form.Control
    type = "date"
    value = { this.state.closingDate }
    onChange = { this.handleDateChange }
  />
</Form.Group>
```

At the moment e.timeStamp gives me a four or five digit number.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19709793/convert-date-from-dd-mm-yyyy-to-yyyy-mm-dd-in-javascript - this should help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
  handleDateChange = e => {
    const date = new Date(e.target.value);
    const timestamp = date.getTime();

    console.log(timestamp)

    this.setState({
      closingDate: e.target.value
    })
  }
```

[image: Edit great-hamilton-qh8x1]