# Javascript string won't conver to new Date object - 'Invalid Date' error

Tags: javascript

I have the following code, with the aim of changing the format of a date from "18/11/2020" to "2020-11-18":

```
        var dateSearched = $("#InputDate").val(); // prints "18/11/2020"
        var dateObject = new Date(dateSearched);
        var formattedDate = dateObject.toISOString().split('T')[0];
```

The issue is that the `dateObject` has an error of Invalid Date.

When debugging `dateSearched` is formatted as a string "18/11/2020", although when hovering over the variable in my code, it says `(local var) dateSearched: string | number | string []` which I suspect might be the cause? I tried using `dateSearched.toString()` but this does not work.

Can  anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: an example would be appreciated

Comment: Please refer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19709793/convert-date-from-dd-mm-yyyy-to-yyyy-mm-dd-in-javascript/19709868