# Convert DD-MM-YYYY to YYYY-MM-DD format using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to convert date format (DD-MM-YYYY) to (YYYY-MM-DD).i use this javascript code.it's doesn't work.

```
 function calbill()
    {
    var edate=document.getElementById("edate").value; //03-11-2014

    var myDate = new Date(edate);
    console.log(myDate);
    var d = myDate.getDate();
    var m =  myDate.getMonth();
    m += 1;  
    var y = myDate.getFullYear();

        var newdate=(y+ "-" + m + "-" + d);

alert (""+newdate); //It's display "NaN-NaN-NaN"
    }
```

Comment: Do not rely on what `Date` constructor will parse. Never. Seriously. Don't do it. Also read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25865621/1207195) and check some other linked posts.

Comment: Ok, what does "it doesn't work" mean? What does it do instead?

Comment: @Juhana when i add "alert (""+newdate);".it's Display "NaN-NaN-NaN"

Answer (score 103, accepted):

This should do the magic

```
var date = "03-11-2014";
var newdate = date.split("-").reverse().join("-");
```

Comment: It's come like this 03-11-2014.I want to convert it to 2014-11-03.

Comment: If it is your answer please consider accepting the answer, by clicking on the hallow check mark, thanks :)

Comment: Just the simplicity I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

Don't use the Date constructor to parse strings, it's extremely unreliable. If you just want to reformat a DD-MM-YYYY string to YYYY-MM-DD then just do that:

```
function reformatDateString(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  return b.reverse().join('-');
}

console.log(reformatDateString('25-12-2014')); // 2014-12-25
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to convert DD-MM-YYYY to YYYY-MM-DD format using JavaScript:

```
var date = "24/09/2018";
date = date.split("/").reverse().join("/");

var date2 = "24-09-2018";
date2 = date.split("-").reverse().join("-");

console.log(date); //print "2018/09/24"
console.log(date2); //print "2018-09-24"
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please clarify the difference between this and the accepted answer. Thank you.

Comment: For date2, it should be as  

date2 = date2.split("-").reverse().join("-");

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use return newdate:

```
function calbill()
{
var edate=document.getElementById("edate").value;

var myDate = new Date(edate);
console.log(myDate);
var d = myDate.getDate();
var m =  myDate.getMonth();
m += 1;  
var y = myDate.getFullYear();

    var newdate=(y+ "-" + m + "-" + d);
  return newdate;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q51y486a/)

---

But I would simply recommend you to use like @Ehsan answered for you.

Answer (score -1):

First yo have to  add a moment js cdn which is easily available at [here](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/moment.js/)

***then follow this code***

moment(moment('13-01-2020', 'DD-MM-YYYY')).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
// will return 2020-01-13

Comment: This requires an external library. There's no mention of that. There's also no explanation. This answer is unconsidered "unhelpful" on stackoverflow.