# Invalid Date in Firefox - Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, date

I want to put the following string: '10-10-2013 03:04' in a Date object.
It's working in Chrome but Firefox tells me it's an invalid Date. (I guess they mean format?)
I tried to use Date.parse on it but that makes it a NaN.

What to do?

UPDATE:
I used the answer of thefourtheye, but now Chrome actually says it's an invalid date ..

```
var dateString = '10-10-2013 03:04';
dateString = dateString.replace(/-/g, ' ');
var DateToUse = new Date(dateString);
```

Returns an invalid date in Chrome.

Comment: I think this post will solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4321270/regarding-javascript-new-date-and-date-parse

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<script>
    var myDate = new Date("10 10 2013 03:04");
    console.log(myDate);
</script>
```

According to the standard, https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14, space can be used to separate date, month and year. The above example works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Yeah, that works. Only problem is that I 'receive' the date with the '-' between the day, month and year.

Comment: If you want your program to be used in any browser, I would recommend `new Date(dateString.replace("-", " ", "g"))`.

Comment: Yeah, simply used a replace function to remove the dashes and now it's working, thanks.

Comment: Is it? http://jsfiddle.net/thefourtheye/B4FpA/ Try this and see if it works in your Chrome.