# What are the technical differences between new Date(Date.parse(string)) and new Date(string)?

Tags: javascript, string, date

Given the following standardized date string:

```
var dateString = "2010-12-23T23:12:00";
```

I can use one of the following snippets of code to parse it:

**Example 1:**

```
var date = new Date(dateString);
```

**Example 2:**

```
var date = new Date(Date.parse(dateString));
```

---

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4321366/2234742), date parsing is only well-defined when the string is of the format `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`. If the string is in that format, however, I would imagine that the two examples would always return the exact same result.

What are the technical differences between these two approaches to creating a date object from a standardized date string, and do they ever return different results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding the answer to this question shortly after I wrote it. According to the ECMAScript Language Specification, for a string argument these two approaches will yield identical results in standards-compliant browsers.

From the [ECMAScript Language Specification](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-15.9.3.2):

**15.9.3.2 new Date(value):**

> 1. Call ToPrimitive(value).
> 2. If Type(Result(1)) is String, then go to step 5.
>
> ...
>
> 5. Parse Result(1) as a date, in exactly the same manner as for the parse method (15.9.4.2); let V be the time value for this date.

When `new Date(string)` is called, it parses the string in the exact same way as `Date.parse(string)` would. So by calling `new Date(Date.parse(string))` we get the exact same result as `new Date(string)`, but at the performance cost of an extra method call.