# How Date Format supported in Web Browser

Tags: javascript, formatdatetime

I want to ask how the date will be formated in different web browsers, like Chrome, FF, IE, ...For example `YYYY-MM-DD` or `YYYY/MM/DD` or `YYYY, MM, DD`. Which date format can be used for all web browsers.

And what is the difference between `Date.Parse(stringdate)` and `new Date(stringdate)`.

Comment: This isn't a direct answer to your question, but you may wish to take a look at the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4321270/regarding-javascript-new-date-and-date-parse

Comment: Google says: For [Date.Parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse), the date format is expected to be in [RFC-2822](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822#section-3.3) or [ISO 8601 format](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime). The [new Date() constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) is slightly more flexible, because it has several overloads that accept other kinds of input.